# Help buying a calculator program

Tags: linear-programming, calculator

Is there an economical calculator program I can buy that will let me multiply and divide numbers in the hundreds of digits and show all of the digits?

Comment: How will you enter numbers with hundreds of digits?

Comment: And how would you read the output?

Comment: What do you mean by economical? Free?

Comment: Sorry for taking days to get back to you all, been tied up with work. 
@copper, yes by typing in the actual number, hundreds of digits.
Sassatelli, I'd like to see the output on my monitor.
ahulpke, free would be nice but I don't want to spend anything more than a couple of hundred dollars.

Answer (score 2):

The Python programming language is free.  It brings a GUI that you can type arithmetic into and automatically extends from normal integers to arbitrary length integers when needed.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What have you looked for so far? This is likely something you can get for free. A quick search on Google turns up https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm

This is also possible with many programming languages, if that is something you or a colleague is interested in.

Comment: I've looked at Wolfram, but it's a little expensive. Still I would buy it if I can't find anything else.